# How to update total quantity while onChange in A or B column and also how to restrict update without clicking update button in react-ag-grid

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ag-grid-react

Hi can anyone please help me, I am using react-ag-grid and also I am using inline edit.

1. When I edit a row without clicking an update button just I am clicking on the second row the edited row is updated with new values how to restrict this.
2. I am using two columns for sample, column A and column B, when I change Column A or B I want to display total Quantity while onchange without clicking an update button.

I tried in many ways But I am unable to achieve these two points.
[Please find this link which I've tried](https://codesandbox.io/s/long-moon-uhdhbm?file=/src/App.js)